# How to change the distribution in VAE from N(0, 1) to N(0, 10)?

Tags: autoencoder

In VAE, the input is tried to be mapped to a latent space, which has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1 (N ~ (0, 1)). Now I want to change N(0, 1) to N(0, 10), where should I edit? It seems a math problem.

Should I edit the formula of KL divergence

`kld_loss = torch.mean(-0.5 * torch.sum(1 + log_var - mu ** 2 - log_var.exp(), dim=1), dim=0)`

to

`kld_loss = torch.mean(-0.5 * torch.sum(10 + log_var - mu ** 2 - log_var.exp(), dim=1), dim=0)`?

Thanks in advance!